# mapgears ol3-google-maps - TypeError: this.setMap is not a function

Tags: ol3-google-maps

I am trying to use **mapgears/ol3-google-maps**, but even the basic examples are not running. I am getting following error message.

> TypeError: this.setMap is not a function

Comment: Please, provide more details about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including Google Maps API before OL3-Google-Maps fixes the issue.